# Programming Style: Try Catch and External Dependents

Tags: java

I have a simple style question.  In an application that I am writing there are several class methods that include a try/catch block as well as function external to the block that depends on the result of the block.  For example (in psudo code):

```
try {
   start_transaction;
   persist_data;
   stop_transaction;
}
catch {
   rollback_transaction;
}
finally {
}

if (transaction_successful)
   send_message;
```

The only way I can think of for testing if the transaction is successful would be to set a method variable flag in the try catch block and then test it in the if statement.  Of course this would work, however I am curious to know what the conventional "wisdom" is with this?  Maybe "send_message" should be in the try catch block although this may be unneccessary clutter?  I guess this is a fairly straight forward question - just trying to ensure my code is well structured / organised.

Comment: well if you're trying to send a message ONLY if the transaction is successful, i would suggest having it as part of the try block itself. Why do you think it would be a "unnecessary clutter"?

Comment: I guess when I read code I like to see a single function in a single "block" - probably just a hang over from my Fortran days :).  More to the point if the send_message call fails then the transaction would be rolled back.  This would be an issue as the transaction is the primary (and critical) function (rather than the message that the transaction has been successful)

Comment: Since anything else a) introduces at least one additional variable and b) additional logic, I really don't see how you come to the conclusion that putting the send message into the try block adds clutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need to think a little bit more on the proper layering of your software/increasing of a cohesion for this class/method. 
From the provided example it seems that here you have DAL/business Layer mix (persistense + some business activities), that's the primary reason you need to react on the result of the transaction in the same method, right after the catch block.

With proper layering it could look like the following:

- Persistence fails, you indicating this fact by throwing checked/runtime exception to the calling layer (it's up to you to decide how to indicate the failure exactly, depdends on your architectural approach),
- Calling class catches the exception and does error handling - or sends the message in corresponding **try** block right after the call of the '**persisting**' method

Of course you could set the flag (as you've suggested) and use AOP advise to process such situations (esp. in case if **'send_message'** is auxiliary function).

Comment: This is a good point.  The structure of the code could potentially be better.  Essentially there is message processing going on: receive a message, persist some message data and then notify other interested systems that new data has arrived.  If the notification fails then the data should still persist.

Comment: In this case answers of other posters are perfectly applicable here - you could move the send_message in try block. It also looks like classical candidate for sync/async event publishing/distribution design approach usage. So you could rise an event here (to indicate that the message were processed/accepted) and leave the notification task to handlers/subscribers of this event. Depends on technology you use, but usually all of them have something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be simple enough to put it in the `try` block.  "Cluttered code" is a matter of personal preference but this keeps things simple.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (*although this looks pretty evident from your code*) that you're trying to send a message if and only if the transaction is successful, I think it would make sense to put it as part of the try block itself.

In my opinion, it wouldn't be an "unnecessary clutter" because the message needs to be send on success. If the message had parts to send even when the transaction fails, then it would've obviously made sense to keep a flag and track the transaction status (*and modify your message accordingly*)

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the `try` block, but in case an exception is thrown while executing `send_message`, it's best to have its own `catch` block - this is done by specifying the appropriate exception classes.